# Display the content of an html page (URL) in a jQuery modal window?

Tags: jquery, popup, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX classic report and I would like to display an Oracle APEX page in a popup modal window ( detail information of the given record).

I would like to avoid plugins at all costs. Is this possible? I am using APEX 4.1.

Tamas

Comment: Any reason why you don't want plugins? In my opinion, the best solution is the Skillbuilders modal page plugin, I take it you've already seen that?

Comment: Yes. The reason is that I can not use any type of them, just zhe five provided by the plugin.

Comment: Yes, it has predefined themes, but you can also use a custom theme. The plugin simply uses Colorbox to provide the styling for the modal region. If none of those five fit your taste, nothing is stopping you from styling it yourself though? Just saying, if style is what is holding you from using it, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Create a column with link on your report:

- **Link Text:** Whatever you want
- **Target:** URL
- **URL:** javascript:openModal(#YOUR_ID#)

Add the following javascript code to your apex page (*Function and Global Variable Declaration*) changing the URL for the right APP_ID, PAGE_ID and ITEM_NAME of the popup page you want to open:

```
function openModal(vId){
    var url = 'f?p=<APP_ID>:<APP_PAGE>:&SESSION.::NO:RP,62:P<APP_PAGE>_ID:'+vID;
    var $dialog = $('<div id="ModalFacPenDiv" style="overflow:auto;overflow-y: hidden;"> <iframe id="modalID" src="'+url+'" width="900px" height="260px" frameborder="no" style="overflow:auto;"></iframe></div>');
    $($dialog).dialog({ 
        open: function(event, ui){
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
        modal: true , 
        dialogClass: 'noTitle', 
        title: 'YOUR TITLE' , 
        width : 920 , 
        height: 380, 
        buttons: { 
            "Close": function(){ 
                window.parent.doSubmit('REFRESH');
                $(this).dialog("close");} },
        closeOnEscape: false });
}
```

You'll need to set **Embed in Frames** to *allow* or *Allow from same origin* (this one is better/more secure) on **Security Attributes > Browser Security**.

I'm assuming that in the popup page you have the necessary processes to show the info based on some ID.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I started using the script above. The dialogue displays allright, but it is empty. I mean it has a correct title and a close button but the middle is empti. I already tried to pass a fixed APEX page URL as the URL to display, but still, the window is empty.

Any tips?

Comment: The popup will show the apex page that you specify on the link:
var url = 'f?p=<APP_ID>:<APP_PAGE>:&SESSION.::NO:RP,62:P<APP_PAGE>_ID:'+vID;

Did you put anything on the page you specify?

Comment: Uhm, yes. Actually the page is session state protected. The problem is that I don't have a clue how on Earth could I generate the crc check code for the URL, without using Application process.

Comment: You don't need to have that page with SSP since user don't even see the url of the modular.